# How to get last record of each day in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to get last record of each day in mysql.`Location<id, date, place_id>` table has multiple entries on each day. This Location table has place_id and time at which place_id is inserted.

Also taking consider if place_id is not present then return second last record which has place_id. In following table for `NULL, '2016-04-06 18:52:06'` record we are returning `'13664', '2016-04-06 12:57:30'`, which is second last record on '2016-04-06' (6th March) and has place_id.

One more thing, on single day, there would be more place_id, see the following table..

```
   id  ||  place_id || date
   '1',   '47', '2016-04-05 18:09:37'
   '2',   '48', '2016-04-05 12:09:37'
   '3',   '13664', '2016-04-06 12:57:30'
   '4',   '9553', '2016-04-08 10:09:37'
   '5',   NULL, '2016-04-06 18:52:06'
   '6',   '9537', '2016-04-07 03:34:24'
   '7',   '9537', '2016-04-07 03:34:24'
   '8',   '656', '2016-04-07 05:34:24'
   '9',   '7', '2016-04-07 05:34:57'
```

When I run following query it returns following result

**Query** I run the following query but it is giving me wrong result

```
`Location<id, place_id, date>`

select L1.place_id, L1.date from 
     Location1 L1 
Left join
     Location1 L2
on 
     Date(L1.date) = Date(L2.date)
And
    L1.date < L2.date
where 
    L2.date is null

group by L1.date;
```

**Result I want:**

```
 id....place_id ........date   
   '1',   '47',      '2016-04-05 18:09:37'    
   '3',   '13664',   '2016-04-06 12:57:30'  
   '4',   '9553',    '2016-04-08 10:09:37'   
   '9',   '7',       '2016-04-07 05:34:57'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may give it a try:

```
SELECT 
L.id,
L.place_id,
L.date
FROM Location L
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   MAX(date) max_time
  FROM Location
  GROUP BY Date(`date`)
) AS t
ON L.date = t.max_time
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c3b/1/0)

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c3b/3/0)

[***Based on your expected output***]

Comment: Actually I bring the corresponding `place_id` which have max value. No matter whether it's null or not.

Comment: I've modified the query in the sql fiddle. Please check the fiddle.

Comment: Great. It looks fine. After I test with my data base I will accept ur answer, I am up-vote you...

Comment: The query isn't giving info on all the place_ids

Comment: It's your choice whether you want the `id` corresponding to `place_id` or not. If you want the id corresponding the `place_id` then you may use `SQL FIDDLE DEMO2`. Or if you want `id` corresponding to the `max_date` field then you can use `SQL FIDDLE DEMO`

Comment: The query is not supposed to give all the place_ids. @HerpaMoTeH

Comment: Compare the `id` field in DEMO 1 vs Your requirement and DEMO 2 vs your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Location` GROUP BY DATE(`date`) ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

What this query does is group the rows by descending date and show a row for each date.

Get the last record:

```
SELECT * FROM `Location` ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1;
```

Get the last record that doesn't have a **null** as a value:

```
SELECT * FROM `Location` WHERE place_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1;
```

Get records for all the places which are not null:

```
SELECT * FROM `Location` WHERE place_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `place_id` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Last record like - only one record, the last one entered ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, look at the last query, it does the job fast and gives you info on all the place_ids

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
select place_id, max(date) as MaxDate
from foo
where place_id is not NULL
group by place_id
```

Comment: On single day, there would be more place_id, so you can't group by place_id, and also you can't use max because I want the place_id with corresponding date...